# Will the Honeywell wifi thermostat work

Tags: wiring, thermostat

Can I get the thermostat with this configuration?[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you figure out where the blue wire goes at the furnace end of the cable?

Comment: It is coiled just like that with the wires in the furnace. Not connected to anything

Answer (score 1):

### Easy enough

Simply uncoil and strip back the blue wire at the furnace end, then tuck it under the "24V COM" terminal there.  Then you can hook it up to the C terminal on your new thermostat and everything should work!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Will the red on the com be attached to it as well in the furnace?

Comment: @Bryandshaw -- yes, the current red wire stays put there (it goes off to your A/C outdoor unit)